# Report error in vs code but works well in clion

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    /*  */
    cout << endl;
}
```

my c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**"],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": [
          "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
      }
    ],
    "version": 4
  }
```

error message:

```
expected ';' at end of declaration
range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
```

It works out fine on my clion and demo in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac, so I guess there is some problem with my vs code settings.

Comment: `c_cpp_properties.json` has nothing to do with how you build your code.

Comment: Resolved. Thanks.